# Error Msg: A new password should be set for this login without specifying the old password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Good day,
 I have a SQL Server job that keeps on failing. As per checking the error msg states that :

> A new password should be set for this login without specifying the old
>   password.

I did some research and all the resources I've found suggest to reset the SQL server login password since it might be expired. I looked at the properties of the SQL Server Login pointed by the error but enforce password expiration is not activated. I would like to know what is the posible cause of this error. Hope you could help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server Agent login? If this is a different service account running. Also, what account is the job being run as?

Comment: yes @WEI_DBA I've check the SQL Server Agent Login. all seems fine with it since the other jobs are running fine. Also, job is owned by sa..